# Repeat each row of matrix multiple times

Tags: matlab

Given the following matrix:

```
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

For `k = 3`, I want the following output:

```
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
2 2 2
2 2 2
2 2 2
3 3 3
3 3 3
3 3 3
```

Is there a smart way to do this in vectorized manner in MATLAB?

Comment: Even though the primary linked duplicate deals with a 1-D vector, the solution extends easily to the 2-D case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`repelem`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html):

```
k = 3;
a =[1 1 1
    2 2 2
    3 3 3]
repelem(a,k,1)
```